# Toggle between two tabs with different dynatrees using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs with tabs, I need to write a javascript or jquery script that will allow for the content to be switched back and forth onclick of the appropriate tab name.

I created a fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sgnZS/3/).  Although I haven't even begun to write the javascript yet.  Can someone take a look at it for me?  It seems like it should be pretty straight forward:

(ID's updated)

- show div1 on ready,
- Hide div1, show div2 onclick link1,
- hide div2, show div1 onclick link2

I first tried using

```
$('#showTree').click(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').show();
}),
    $('#showTree2').click(function() {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
});
```

but this did not work. Would someone mind taking a look at the fiddle and giving me some advice?  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Please fix your duplicated `id`s. The `id` attribute must be unique

Comment: @Alexander Since the links were inside the divs, the function hid them.  All I want to do is toggle between the two tabs, but I cannot use jquery tabs.

Comment: @Alexander -id's updated

Comment: You still have duplicated `id`s e.g. `showTree` and `showTree2` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use some class to know which tab is currently active. Try .toggle() show/hide
working example here
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/DmaG5/)

```
$('span.a, span.b').click(function() {
if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('span.a, span.b').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('div.a, div.b').toggle();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have an invalid markup. Because of this `#div2` has become a children of `#div1`. At the moment of hiding `#div1`, `#div2` is also hidden.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
```

You need to match the ending tags.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you need to fix your duplicated `id`. Specially `#showTree` and `#showTree2`. A quick fix is using classnames instead. That is,

```
<nav class="sidebartabs">
  <a href="#" class="showTree">Questions by Folder</a>
  <a href="#" class="showTree2">Questions by Category</a>
</nav>
```

Hiding `#div2` at page load can be done by using CSS.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<div id="div2" class="hidden">...</div>
```

[See a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7AeY2/)